# Не удается подключиться к виртуальной машине Azure

Tags: azure

Есть аккаунт Azure. Есть задача: надо создать виртуальную машину и подключиться к ней. Если первый шаг интуитивен, то со вторым возникает проблема.

Итак, есть стабильно работающая виртуальная машина. В ней прописаны EndPoints. Кнопка "подключение" недоступна, как и подключение при помощи родного виндового "Подключение к удаленному рабочему столу". Было перелопачено множество материалов на MSDN: виртуальная машина перезагружалась, настройки сбрасывались. Ничего не помогает. Подскажите новичку советом, как можно решить это проблему.

Comment: А с Облачной службой всё в порядке?

Comment: Да. Все работает. Причем такая проблема уже на втором аккаунте. Есть подозрение, что делаю что-то кардинально неправильно.

Comment: A что значит 'стабильно работающая'? Как вы это проверили? Обычно нужно чтобы rdp порт был сконфигурирован в endpoints. Вы уверены что конфигурация endpoints корректна?  Как вариант обратитесь в тех поддержку аzure. Они смогут помочь.

Comment: Вы машину создавали в старом или новом портале? В зависимости от этого разные настройки по умолчанию.

Comment: На новом. Большая часть материалов описывает старый.

Answer (score 3):

Подозреваю, что, т.к. виртуальная машина была создана на новом портале, был выбран по умолчанию тип Resource Manager (т.е. не классическая виртуальная машина).

В этом случае, у этой VM отсутвует публичный адрес, его нужно создать дополнительно. В Settings -> Network Interfaces -> IP Addresses -> Public IP Address -> Enabled -> Create New.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого иконка удаленного соединения должна стать активной (если мы говорим о Windows VM). В случае с Linux этот адрес следует использовать для подключения по SSH.